# Segmentation Fault in For Loop

Tags: c, opencv, for-loop, segmentation-fault

I have the following code which keeps on giving segmentation fault after execution for few number times.

```
//pasting second image
for(n32i=0;n32i<(SrcImageHeight2);n32i++)
{
  //printf("\n%di",i);
  for(n32j=0;n32j<(SrcImageWidth2);n32j++)
  { 
    int x=n32j;
    int y=n32i;  

    CvMat *tempMatrix1 = cvCreateMat(3,1,CV_32FC1);
    printf("\n Here ,  %d , %d , %d , %d ,%d ,%d , x = %d , y = %d" , n32k , n32j , n32i , SrcImageChannels2 , SrcImageWidth2 , SrcImageHeight2 , x, y);        
    CV_MAT_ELEM(*tempMatrix1, float,0,0) =x;
    printf("\n There ,  %d , %d , %d , %d ,%d ,%d" , n32k , n32j , n32i , SrcImageChannels2 , SrcImageWidth2 , SrcImageHeight2);        
    CV_MAT_ELEM(*tempMatrix1, float,1,0) =y;
    CV_MAT_ELEM(*tempMatrix1, float,2,0) =1;
    cvMatMul(matrixH,tempMatrix1,tempMatrix1);
    x=*((float *)CV_MAT_ELEM_PTR(*tempMatrix1,0,0))/ *((float *)CV_MAT_ELEM_PTR(*tempMatrix1,2,0));
    y=*((float *)CV_MAT_ELEM_PTR(*tempMatrix1,1,0))/ *((float *)CV_MAT_ELEM_PTR(*tempMatrix1,2,0));

    for(n32k=0;n32k<(SrcImageChannels2);n32k++)
    {   
        if(DstImageData[(y+h)*DstImageStep+(x+w)*DstImageChannels+n32k] ==0)
        {   
          DstImageData[(y+h)*DstImageStep+(x+w)*DstImageChannels+n32k]=SrcImageData2[n32i*SrcImageStep2+n32j*SrcImageChannels2+n32k];
        }
    }
  }
}
```

The error is on the the line `CV_MAT_ELEM(*tempMatrix1, float,0,0) =x;` ,  I do not understand why it is happening , because it's just an assignment , and works fine for earlier execution (i.e. execution before the error).

Comment: is it possible that `cvCreateMat` fails? have you checked tempMatrix1 before the crash?

Comment: Ensure tempMatrix1 is a valid address... add if(tempMatrix1 != NULL) before calling CV_MAT_ELEM().

Answer (score 2):

It sounds as if `cvCreateMat()` does dynamic memory allocation, but you fail to:

1. Check that it succeeds
2. Free it when you're done with it.

These are both bad, together they are very bad.